# The Error in Twittersession Callback with Android Rtrofit 2

Tags: android

I have Social(Twitter) Login in my project.  Following code.

```
    twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            Log.i("Status", "Twitter Logged in..." + result.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
            Log.i("Status", "Instagram NOT Logged in...");
        }
    });
```

Then I used retrofit 2.0 for backend api of my app.  So I added the following code on builde.gradle.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
```

After I add the code, I had the error in the "(new Callback)".
This problem !!!

Comment: new Callback<TwitterSession> of the code

Comment: twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>()

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your error in detail.

There could be a package ambiguity between 
`retrofit.Callback` and `javax.security.auth.callback.Callback`. Make sure you resolve them.

Comment: twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>())